# How to determine the value of a predefined integral? Calculus

Tags: calculus

I have this question on my calc book that I couldn't understand quite a bit! What should I do exactly? And how? The question goes like:

> Assume some predefined integrals:

[image]

> Determine the value of the following integral:

[image]

> How would I do it since they already provided the integrals on the top (predefined)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that the integral is linear:
$$\int_a^b \alpha\, g(x) + \beta\, h(x) \,dx = \alpha \int_a^b  g(x) \,dx + \beta \int h(x) \,dx$$
You're given the two integrals on the RHS, so you can calculate the integral on the LHS.

$$\int_5^{10} \left( \tfrac{1}{4} \left( 2g(x)-5h(x) \right) \right) dx = \int_5^{10}  \tfrac{1}{2}g(x)-\tfrac{5}{4}h(x) \, dx = \tfrac{1}{2} \int_5^{10} g(x)\,dx-\tfrac{5}{4} \int_5^{10} h(x)\,dx $$

Comment: Would you please complete your answer to the end so I can better understand what you did? Also, would you explain why you shifted the constant multiplayers to the inverse (2 and 5)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added an extra step (using the linearity); the two integrals you end up with are given. For the constants: I just expanded the brackets (multiplying 1/4 with 2 and -5).

Comment: Thanks! that helps a lot! Though, I got 16. Is it this the correct value of that integral or I missed something out? For example, do I need to add the C at the end of that value and assign it to 0 to get C? Or that's it?

Comment: Seems good! The constant of integration is something for indefinite integrals (to get all antiderivatives); you don't need that here (definite integrals).